# if f is entire ,then,which of the following cannot be image of upper half plane under $f$

Tags: complex-analysis

consider the following problem:

suppose $f$ is an entire function such that $f(\Bbb R)\subset\Bbb R$.let $\Bbb H=\{x+iy:y\gt0\}$,then $f(\Bbb H)$ cannot be

(a) unit disk

(b) $\{x+iy:x\gt 0\}$

(c) $\{x+iy:y\lt0\}$

(d) $\{z:\lvert z\rvert\gt 1\}$

i have tried the following:

there exists biholomorphic maps from $\Bbb H$ to unit disk,so,(a) is false,but how do i check for options (b),(c) and(d)?

thanks for your time in advance..

Comment: Try to construct functions which map the open upper half plane to the corresponding sets. Also, is it the open or closed unit disc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is entire and $f$ is real on the real axis, then $f(z^*) = f(z)^*$ for all $z\in \mathbb C.$ (Here $z^*$ is the conjugate of $z.$) This is crucial in this problem. For one thing, it implies $f(\mathbb H^*) = f(\mathbb H)^*.$

(a) You were thinking of conformal maps of $\mathbb H$ onto $\mathbb D.$ But none of those maps is entire. So we have to think a different way: If $f(\mathbb H)=\mathbb D,$ then $f(\mathbb H^*) = \mathbb D^* =\mathbb D.$ It follows that $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb C.$ By Liouville, $f$ is constant, contradiction. Therefore $f(\mathbb H)=\mathbb D$ is impossible.

I'll give hints for (b), (c), (d):

(b) Let $U$ denote the open right half plane. If $f(\mathbb H)=U,$ then $f(\mathbb H^*) = U^* =U.$

(c ) This one has a trivial solution.

(d) Note that $\{|z|>1\}^* = \{|z|>1\}.$